# get 'this' tab of content script (not selected, not active tab)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

There are quite some similar question but they all comes down to `chrome.tabs.getSelected` or `chrome.tabs.query` API which is not suitable in my case.

Basically what I need to do is to get an `id` of the tab where the script is running from - so it's not necessarily an active or selected tab.

As per [the doc](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-getCurrent):

> **getCurrent** chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function callback)
>
> Gets the tab that this script call is being made from. May be
>   undefined if called from a non-tab context (for example: a background
>   page or popup view).

Which implies that it should work from content script but `chrome.tabs` is undefined in content script. Why is it so? Is there any way to know `this` tab data (from where the content script is running and not from selected or active tab)?

Even though the doc says the `tabs` permission is not mandatory for the most APIs I've anyway added it to the manifest with no luck:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": ...
  "permissions": [
    ...
    "tabs",
    ...
}
```

Any ideas are much appreciated

The use case for `get current/this tab` is that when the extension does its work it needs to reload a page where it's running from as part of the working flow and user can be on different tab or in different window. The extension's script still needs to get the correct tabId to keep working as expected.

Comment: You can't use `chrome.tabs` in a content script. Only 4 chrome API are allowed (listed in the [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)).

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks - what is the use case for the getCurrent api then? It returns undefined tab if run from background (which is obvious) but in script it's not available. The method looks quite strange to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, seems like I've figured out an answer to my question.

The trick is to send a message to background script and extract `sender` data from there. Sender will include `tab` object where the script is running from.

I'm using `ports` so this is what I'll describe as example below:

On content script side:

```
    var port = chrome.extension.connect({
        name: "some name"
    });

    port.postMessage({"key":"some json here"})
```

On Background side:

```
chrome.extension.onConnect.addListener(function (port) {
    console.log(port.sender.tab)
})
```

`port.sender` is a [MessageSender](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime#type-MessageSender) object that will contain tabId (and tabUrl if "tabs" permission is added to the manifest)

In my case I'm just sending tabId back from background to the content script:

```
port.postMessage({"tabId":port.sender.tab.id})
```

More on this can be found in [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging) doc and in [this api doc](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime#type-MessageSender)

Comment: This is, unfortunately, the best way to go on this. Although I would recommend sending a one-off message rather than opening a port, since this is not a long-lived connection.

Comment: If you've solved your problem, please accept it as the correct answer for the benefit of future users.

Comment: @err1100, there is 2 days gap before I can accept it - no way I can do it earlier - I honestly tried ;)

Answer (score 1):

Effectively, you can only use `chrome.tabs.getCurrent` on a page from the `chrome-extension://` scheme (opened as your extension's Options page or via `chrome.tabs.create` or `chrome.windows.create`), or if you're using `chrome_url_overrides`. The background, popup, and embedded options pages don't have a current tab, and the API doesn't exist in a content script.

Comment: Josh thanks, you saved my day! im tried to figure out why my chrome-extension://
page invalidates context with chrome.tabs.query, but with chrome.tabs.getCurrent all works fine